# Is it nefarious to ask about invisible FTP of desktop screenshots?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I encountered an answer on the SO Low Quality Posts review queue where the answerer states:

> This guy is building malware

So, I checked out the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181605/how-do-i-code-my-program-so-that-it-can-automatically-upload-files-to-an-sftp-ft):

> My c# Visual Studio program takes screenshots periodically and saves them to the computer it's installed on. I want the program to be able to take these files and automatically upload them to a FTP or SFTP server at a set interval, but I need the program as a whole to be virtually invisible (including this feature) so that anyone using the computer wouldn't know it's installed. I also need this method to be 100% free so no buying a server or anything like that.

I guess it is already off-topic (asking for free FTP service and no code for 'My c# Visual studio program) for two reasons and also too broad. However, the OP adds this comment:

> @Karl Gjertsen It's a child monitoring program for my friend. – Traci.Buske Dec 16 '16 at 10:10

So that's a question about:

- silent/ background screenshots
- uploading these screenshots via FTP (without user knowledge one assumes)
- for 'child monitoring'

I think there's a good shot for that qualifying as [nefarious intent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/dealing-with-questions-of-nefarious-intent).

Am I wrong to flag for moderator attention instead of just voting to close (for either of the off-topic reasons, or just too broad)?

Comment: What do you want a moderator to do about it? Delete the person from the Internet? Wouldn't that be nice. Just vote to close as "too broad", like you would any other crappy "question" like this. Don't forget to downvote.

Comment: That's why I am asking here - as I am not confident that just voting to close is proportionate to the 'nefarious' nature of the question - which has the interesting thread of its own. I downvoted question and answer (not an answer). I'm assuming some questions might get the once-over by the mods as answering this question could be a problem

Comment: The community is pretty good at downvoting and closing this kind of stuff.

Comment: *"Is it nefarious to ask about invisible FTP of desktop screenshots"* - not really. Its just an example of a particular network transfer that a piece of software might do when installed on a machine. It would maybe need to set off warning signs when the question asks how to install such a piece of software silently.

Comment: In spite of @pekka's assertion, the question did not get a single CV while it was active.  Nor enough DVs to activate the Roomba.  The site was not yet in hat slumber mode, very popular tag.  The community is incapable of getting rid of lousy content.

Comment: @HansPassant Perhaps the consensus only turned to the content being "lousy" after this meta was created about it.

Comment: @Gimby - thanks for trying to make a counter-point. My discomfort with the question stems from the OP saying `so that anyone using the computer wouldn't know it's installed` - which means they want to send my desktop images somewhere without user consent. This kind of trumps your point about installation. Your comment is reasonable though.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie agree to disagree :) Regardless, you cannot prove the reasonings are malicious in nature unless the OP openly admits it. Until that moment I myself don't really care about the intent, only about the content.

Comment: For what it's worth, as a parent, I've had the need for something like this to monitor activity on a shared computer. Kids do nefarious things, and as a parent, having something like that lends itself to peace of mind. The OP maybe doesn't have malicious intent here. (Also, FWIW, that parent could just tell the child it's installed and running, and he child would believe them ^_^)

Comment: Commenter: *"This is malware designed to invade a user's privacy without their knowledge."* Asker: *"Don't worry, the victim is a child."* Well, that's that moral issue sorted, then.

Comment: @brandonscript If your kid can't handle the responsibility of using the computer, why let them? If you fear that your kid might come across nasty things on the internet, why let them? Secretly spying on your kid or lie to them doesn't sound like the way to go. Anyway, that's for http://parenting.stackexchange.com/ and not SO. This is a classic problem of an inventor who is inventing something that can clearly be used to do very evil things, but justifying it with some hypocrite excuse. I don't think we should encourage malware tutorials "in the name of science".

Comment: @Lundin The same could be said about web filtering, or walking outside for that matter.  It isn't like it's not possible to get around it; it's just a boundary.  But it's a clear cut line instead of grey area, and it significantly reduces the temptation.  Or in this case, it could be something where Kid might otherwise think he's getting away with it (in secret), whereas now he knows there are screenshots getting sent.  Like security cameras in a gas station.  I'm not saying that this *is* what's happening, but it could be.  And to let the user know each time the picture [...]

Comment: [...] is taken would defeat the purpose.  The inventor could very well be thinking of something evil, but since we have no proof, we can't base our judgement off of a possibility.  Like Carpetsmoker points out below, if we let the possibility of cars being used to run people over stop us from driving, we'd be missing out on a lot of great benefits.

Comment: Substitute "very young but tech savvy teenager who has serious Porn addiction and is in therapy for it" for "Child".

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This question is (far) too broad and should be closed (and then hopefully quickly deleted) which will solve the problem. There's no real need to worry about the "malicious intent" part as such.

From what I've seen, this is a common pattern with almost *all* questions that are obviously trying to do something malicious. This is hardly surprising, because an on-topic, specific, and answerable question usually doesn't deal with concepts that are high-level enough to make it obvious that the author is trying to do something malicious.

Of course, specific on-topic questions *can* still show malicious intent – and you may choose to not answer or downvote them – but it'll be hard to outlaw those questions. Almost any answer can be used for malicious intent in some way. Just like hammers and cars and beer bottles can be used for malicious intent.

Comment: I voted to close as 'too broad'. Your comment that there is a common pattern is interesting - thanks.

Comment: The problems you describe are not limited to malicious questions: ["btw I can't code other than copying and pasting a piece of code to powershell"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568838/how-to-push-windows-10-notifications-to-an-android-phone) :-)

Comment: And we *know* that people have asked questions for nefarious purposes. We know because at least one person was tried and convicted specifically because they carried out their purpose, and their Stack Overflow questions were used as evidence against them: http://www.slate.com/blogs/future_tense/2013/10/02/silk_road_s_dread_pirate_ross_ulbricht_asked_stack_overflow_question_under.html. We could not have known *at the time* what the intent of the asker was, of course.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - thanks for the link - as a mod do you think the community should DV/ CV or flag for moderation? I imagine some mods may say *maybe I can lean a little on this question and make some points about content without going so far as to close the question - just make a point in a polite and non-editorialising manner*

Comment: @RobinMackenzie: moderators can't and won't enforce laws; what is 'nefarious' in one jurisdiction could be legal in another. We certainly won't determine what the intent of a question is, so no, don't flag such posts for moderator attention.

Comment: To be fair, I think the only jurisdiction that matters is the country SO is ran from, right? Sorta the same reason they can't shut down the Pirate bay, I thought.

Comment: @TankorSmash I think it's a bit of a moot point. I can't really think of an *on-topic* question that would be clear-cut illegal. In all cases I've seen it's simply an *educated guess* of malicious intent. e.g. "sending 50,000 emails" *does* have valid use cases. The FTP question that provoked this meta discussion also looks somewhat suspicious at best, but the "malicious intent" is merely an educated guess. It's entirely plausible there isn't any! Besides, "malicious" intent isn't the same as "illegal". In many jurisdictions spam etc. is perfectly legal.

Comment: hmpf. at least Silk Road was there to bring happiness (kinda) into people's life, not stalk the hell out their pr0n watching habits. I'd be much more comfortable if we'd had brought down a real malware programmer. Sadly authorities don't care about malware and crackers, unless they steal their money. </totally-useless-and-uncalled-for-rant>